# (dual boot)Windows crashing on startup after recent ubuntu update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I started using ubuntu for a few weeks and I am learning it bit by bit...
On my lenovo laptop i have windows 10 and ubuntu(20.04.1)on dual boot. Both were working fine for a few weeks. After a recent update on ubuntu(i can't remember what it was but it required a reboot) windows won't boot, it just shows the lenovo startup logo and nothing happens. But ubuntu boots up fine. I still haven't tried anything at this point. Any help would be appreciated
(grub version is 2.04, fast boot disabled, laptop uses UEFI)

Comment: Debugging the Windows side of the boot failures is offtopic here on Ask Ubuntu, we don't provide the Windows support side.  You can get support for that on [Super User](https://superuser.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasWard Then, can i ask if this problem is related to ubuntu's update or related to Grub? Because I believe the problem was from ubuntu

Comment: @Maxjo How do we know that?

Comment: @Pilot6 well...i thought there would be people who had the same issue with me. no luck then :(

Comment: Try boot-repair is Windows is no longer booting up.